# FCM doesn't work on Chrome, but works on Edge and Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am playing with firebase web codelab example from [here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/#0)

Everything works when I run already "completed" lab (from the "web" directory), except one strange problem:
I can't get FCM notifications working on Chrome (Version 80.0.3987.163 (Official Build) (64-bit)).

It works when the same site runs in Firefox and Edge, but on Chrome it doesn't work neither locally nor deployed on firebase hosting (with https links).

I get a request to allow notifications from the site, get a token, token is stored in db and can be seen in the console, but when I paste this token into postman - nothing happens (fcm send returns success, and fails if I pass wrong server credentials or token).
Exactly same workflow with same postman command works on Firefox and Edge.

As it is Google 100% code (directly cloned from [here](https://github.com/firebase/codelab-friendlychat-web)) I doubt the problem is with the code, and if it works for Edge and Firefox apparently all credentials are correct.

Update:
added relevant code samples
from public/index.html

```
<!-- Import and configure the Firebase SDK -->
<!-- These scripts are made available when the app is served or deployed on Firebase Hosting -->
<!-- If you do not want to serve/host your project using Firebase Hosting see https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup -->
<script src="/__/firebase/7.14.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="/__/firebase/7.14.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="/__/firebase/7.14.1/firebase-storage.js"></script>
<script src="/__/firebase/7.14.1/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
<script src="/__/firebase/7.14.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
<script src="/__/firebase/7.14.1/firebase-performance.js"></script>
<script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>

<script src="scripts/main.js"></script>
```

from public/firebase-messaging-sw.js

```
// Import and configure the Firebase SDK
// These scripts are made available when the app is served or deployed on Firebase Hosting
// If you do not want to serve/host your project using Firebase Hosting see https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup
importScripts('/__/firebase/7.14.1/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('/__/firebase/7.14.1/firebase-messaging.js');
importScripts('/__/firebase/init.js');

firebase.messaging();
```

Postman request:

```
{
"notification": {
"title": "New chat message!",
"body": "There is a new message in FriendlyChat",
"icon": "/images/profile_placeholder.png",
"click_action": "http://localhost:5000"
},
"to":"cjXXXXXXXm9l"
}
```

Response to postman request:

```
{
"multicast_id": 7762212940520416194,
"success": 1,
"failure": 0,
"canonical_ids": 0,
"results": [
    {
        "message_id": "0:1587665587020317%e609af1cf9fd7ecd"
    }
]
}
```

Anybody has any idea what it can be?